# Getting historic build times from Visual Studio/TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

Since the "Team Explorer - Builds" panel shows a little histogram of recent build times, this information is obviously available in the database; is there some was to extract historic build times in order to do statistical analysis and show how times are varying as the project progresses?

FYI: VS2013, TFS2010

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the QueryBuilds method to get that info. You can find an example in PowerShell [here](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2012/09/fastest-way-to-get-list-of-builds-using-ibuildserver-querybuilds-2/).

The data is stored in the [IBuildDetail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddetail_properties.aspx) object that can be retrieved with the above PowerShell or similar API calls. Once you have a IBuildDetail object you can use the StartTime and EndTime properties to calculate the length of time that it took.